# Why when changing the width property in figure causes some spaces between the title and the text?

Tags: spacing, width, sidewaysfigure

This is the LaTex code:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
   \includegraphics[width=80mm]{PLA.pdf}
  \caption{Some figure}
\end{figure}
```

When I change the width to 80 it causes the problem but when I change the width to something like 55, there will be no problem.

The spaces are depicted in the picture:

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I just reproduced another minimal working example but the problem disappeared! Something is causing this spacing problem which is not easy to trace.

Comment: If you have multiple big figures, it may be a normal behaviour as latex tries to fill the page the best way, leading to some variable spacing.

Comment: \raggedbottom might be helpful

Comment: @leandriis that helped! Thank you!